# how to preserve kong domain name in ui redirection

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I am using kong 2.5 for APIs and Microservice routing and I got a requirement to place react ui application behind kong.so,I have created below service pointing to my UI application.

```
{host : www.example.com,
protocol : http,
path: /,
port: 80}
```

I have created route for the same.

```
{
Host : www.mykongeg.com,
Paths : {/maps/home},
strip_path : false,
preserve_host : false
}
```

Kong domain : [www.kongeg.com](http://www.kongeg.com)

So when I tried to access ‘www.kongeg.com/maps/home’, it is redirecting to ‘www.example.com/maps/home’ on browser.

is it possible to preserve kong domain name on browser without modifying to service url ?. so when I access ‘www.kongeg.com/maps/home’, it should display content returned by ‘www.example.com/maps/home’.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you share your configuration ?
This seems very classic proxy conf

Comment: I have only below configuration in Kong datastore and I haven't tried any proxy configuration in conf file.   
Services :
```{
name : dev-ui-maps-home,
retries : 5,
protocol : http,
host : www.mykongeg.com,
port : 80,
path : /,
connect_timeout : 60000,
write_timeout : 60000
} 
```
Routes:
```
{
name : dev-ui-maps-home-route,
protocol : {http,https},
host : "www.example.com"
path : {/maps/home},
regex_priority : 0,
strip_path : false,
preserve_host : false,
https_redirect_status_code : 426,
path_handling : v1,
request_buffering : true,
response_buffering : true
}```

Comment: Hi @Orel, It's a UI redirection not a API call